# Hide environment variable from OMS

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I have a k8s cluster on Azure, and push all logs to OMS. I've noticed there is a table `ContainerInventory` with a column `EnvironmentVar` which stores each of a container's environment variables in plain text. Some of these variables are sensitive credentials passed to the container through k8s secrets. Is there any way to restrict OMS to not store this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you may disable collection of environmental variables on a new or existing container by setting the variable AZMON_COLLECT_ENV 
with a value of False in your Kubernetes deployment yaml configuration file. For more information, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-manage-agent#how-to-disable-environment-variable-collection-on-a-container) document. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!